# AWS Cognito using a custom domain need A record

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-route53

I am trying to set up a simple portfolio-building website, and I am using AWS Cognito.  I am trying to use a custom domain, but when I press save changes I get the following error.

"Custom domain is not a valid subdomain: Was not able to resolve the root domain, please ensure an A record exists for the root domain. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 26a22647-f70f-41e7-b552-3ee883351858)"

I'm not familiar with A records, if this is even the problem.  How do I create them and what IP address should I use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cognito endpoint will need to be a subdomain. It can not be the apex record of the DNS hosted zone.

Comment: Thanks for helping @mokugo-devops! I know.  For the endpoint I am using auth.domain.com.  It is still saying I need to generate an A record though.

Comment: Hi, Yes if you are using a custom domain you will need to add a DNS record for this.

If you have access to the DNS for your root domain, you would add a record for this.

If its Route 53, then add an A record with an Alias target to the CloudFront record that is provided to you. Else set a CNAME against the record name.

Comment: Thanks again @mokugo-devops.  How do I serve a react app from this?

Comment: Hi @mokugo-devops. Also, how do I get the alias target to the cloudfront record?

Comment: Hi Matt,

If you're using Route 53 add your record as an A Record, then select Alias. A dropdown list should occur or you should be able to paste the value instead

Comment: Thanks @mokugo-devops!

Comment: Where to get the value for A record?